# How to send mail from Mac Application

Tags: cocoa, email

I am new in developing Mac Applications, In my application i need to open mail compose just like in iPhone, But am not able to find which frame i have to use.

Any one know about this, How to open Mail compose window.

Regards

Comment: Bear in mind that not all Mac users use Mail.  There's Thunderbird and other programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this is to use the NSAppleScript class. If you are at least semi-familiar with AppleScript, it shouldn't be too hard.

```
    NSAppleScript *mailScript;
    NSString *scriptString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"Mail\"\nmake new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:\"%@\", content:\"%@\"}\nactivate\nend tell",subject,body];
    mailScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptString];
    [mailScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

Comment: Hi tippy, Thanks its working, I have a requirement for attaching a file to the mail How can i achieve this, Can you please help me